# android-x86 build on ubuntu 12.10 with gcc 4.7

Tags: android, ubuntu, build, compiler-errors

I am building android source-code downloaded from android-x86 website http://www.android-x86.org/getsourcecode for x86 machine, and host machine is x86 with ubuntu 12.10 and GCC 4.7,
while giving make command its throwing several of scope & declaration errors and aborting compilation,I have installed all required packages and Java version is also Sun's JAva package,
whether I am missing something or compatibility is an issue?